# How to find out the biggest number in many documents that contains different numbers

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, numeric-data

For example, there are some temperature data at those folders in different time.
`temps.txt` contains the temperature number. So how can I use bash script to find out the maximum temperature? (the results only show the date,time and number of temperature,e.g. `./2011.10.20/00:00/temps.txt 27C`).

```
$ ls
2011.10.20  2012.01.20  2012.04.16  2012.07.12  2012.10.07
2011.10.21  2012.01.21  2012.04.17  2012.07.13  2012.10.08
2011.10.22  2012.01.22  2012.04.18  2012.07.14  2012.10.09
$ cd 2011.10.20

$ ls    
00:00   02:25   04:50   07:15   09:40   12:05   14:30   16:55   19:20   21:45
00:05   02:30   04:55   07:20   09:45   12:10   14:35   17:00   19:25   21:50
00:10   02:35   05:00   07:25   09:50   12:15   14:40   17:05   19:30   21:55
$ cd 00:00
$ ls
temps.txt
$ cat temps.txt
Sensor   Location              Temp
------   --------              ----
#1        PROCESSOR_ZONE       27C/80F
```

Comment: Why don't you think of the algorithm that you might use and then try to script it in bash and tell us where you are having problems.

Comment: You can use `find` to get a list of each file and then `sort` on each file to have it sorted by temperature; after that it's a matter of formatting the output to your taste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the combination `find`, `grep` and `awk` command to get the desired result. The below is a oneliner which will print the file which has the maximum temperature recorded.

```
find . -mindepth 3 -exec echo -n "{} " \; -exec grep "PROCESSOR_ZONE" {} \; |
awk '{
    split($4,val,"/");
    gsub("C","",val[1]);
    if (max<val[1]) {file=$1; max=val[1]}
} END {print(file)}'
```

Output

```
./2012.04.16/00:10/temps.txt
```

Below is the `script` version of the oneliner.

```
#!/bin/bash

# The path where temperature directories and files are kept
path="/tmp/tmp.ADntEuTlUT/"

# Temp file
tempfile=$(mktemp)

# Get the list of files name and their corresponding
# temperature data.
find "${path}" -mindepth 3 -exec echo -n "{} " \; -exec grep "PROCESSOR_ZONE" {} \; > "${tempfile}"

# Parse though the temp file to find the maximum 
# temperature based on Celsius
awk '{split($4,val,"/");gsub("C","",val[1]);if(max<val[1]){file=$1;max=val[1]}} END{print(file)}' "${tempfile}"

# Removing the temp file
rm -f "${tempfile}"
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `grep`, assuming no file paths contain newline characters:

```
grep -rHPo 'PROCESSOR_ZONE\s+\K\d+C' . | awk -F: '
   0+$NF >= max {max = $NF; text = $0}; END {print text}'
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution makes used of the split function in awk to split the fields and do the numeric reverse sort to pop the max number to the top.

```
find . -name "temps.txt" -print|xargs tail -n 1 | awk '{split($NF,temp,"[CF/]");print temp[1]}'|sort -r | head -n 1
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term value.
Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what
limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: That doesn't show the file name. Note that your need `sort -rn` for a numerical sort.